# Showing div (modal) close to a highlighted text

Tags: javascript, text, popup, selected

I would like to show a div (modal) close to a selected (highlighted) text in the page.
I get the selected text positions (start and end positions) but now, I dont know how the modal div can be positioned in the center of the highlighted text.

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute positioning.

> $(modal).css('position','absolute')

in the same fashion you can set attributes top and left to whatever number you need. This will place the modal where ever you need.